Avoid putting 'use foo' into every file using my macro
I have a file defining a macro that uses the regex crate. Is there any chance to avoid putting use regex::Regex; into all files using my macro?

Yes, by fully specifying it: ::regex::Regex.

How about explicitly writing regex::Regex instead of just Regex in your macro?

I can think of 2 possibilities:

You use fully qualified paths everywhere you use a struct:
macro_rules! foo {
    () => {
        let bar: ::regex::Regex;
        let baz: ::regex::Regex;
    }
}


You add the import to your macro (in a scope as to not clash with imports from the environment):
macro_rules! foo {
    () => {{ // NB: double `{` to create a scope
        use ::regex::Regex;
        let bar: Regex;
        let baz: Regex;
    }}
}



